# Bootstrap NavBar Max-Height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a nav-bar menu with bootstrap, however it seems to behave oddly on devices > 992 width. The menu seems to lose the background color on the last 3 links and it doesn't have the scrollbar.

I've created a fiddle [navbar fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jalz/4q4vLs07/) showing you what I mean. If the width is below 992, the navbar menu collapses fine, however as soon as you reach that magic medium device number the navbar loses the scrolling ability or the background color.

Can someone advise me as to what I need to do to fix this behaviour?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top hidden-md hidden-lg" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span style="background-color:white" class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span style="background-color:white" class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span style="background-color:white" class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span style="background-color:white" class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div><!-- end navbar-header -->


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav-body">
<li><a  href="My Link 1" target="_blank">My Link 1</a></li>
<li><a  href="My Link 1" class="">My Link 1</a></li>
<li><a  href="My Link 1" class="">My Link 1</a></li>
<li><a  href="My Link 1" class="">My Link 1</a></li>
<li><a  href="My Link 1" class="">My Link 1</a></li>
<li><a  href="My Link 1" class="">My Link 1</a></li>
<li><a  href="My Link 1" class="">My Link 1</a></li>
<li><a  href="My Link 1" class="">My Link 1</a></li>
<li><a  href="My Link 1" class="">My Link 1</a></li>
<li><a  href="My Link 1" class="">My Link 1</a></li>
</ul>
        </div>

    </div><!-- end container -->
</nav><!-- end navbar -->
```

MY CSS

```
header .logo {
width: 120px;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
background: transparent;
padding-left: 0;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -60px;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.05s;
z-index: 2;
}



p, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p {
line-height: 1.5em;
}

a, h1, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
color: #4286f4;
}

a:hover {color: #4286f4;}

h1 {
font-size: 2em;
margin: 0.67em 0;
}



header .header-social {
position: absolute;
display: block;
width: 25px;
height: 150px;
top: 10px;
right: 15px;
z-index: 2;
}

header .header-social {
float: right;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
padding: 15px;
width: auto;
top: unset;
right: unset;
height: auto;
}

header .header-social ul li {
display: inline-block;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: #4286f4;
margin-right: 5px;
}

 header .header-social ul li a path {
 fill: white;
 }

button.navbar-toggle {background-color: #4286f4;}

.navbar-nav {background-color: #fff;}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
color: #585960;
display: block;
line-height:.8em;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 0.85em;
background-color: #fff;
border-style: solid;
border-color:#cccccc;
border-top-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
color: #fff;
background-color: #4286f4;
}

.navbar-brand {height: 70px;}


ul.nav-body {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0; 



}

.nav-body > li a {


color: #585960;
display: block;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2em;
font-weight: bolder;
padding: 10px;

position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;

border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;

overflow: auto; 



}


.nav-body > li a:hover {
background-color: #555;
color: #fff;
}


.nav-body > li a.selectedPage   {
background: #4286f4;
color: #fff;
}



@media (min-width: 768px) {
header .logo {
left: 0;
padding-left: 30px;
width: 180px;
height: 180px;
margin-left: 0;
}

}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
body {padding-top: 70px;}


.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.navbar-text {
    float: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}



.navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
    display: block!important;
}


.collapsing {
    overflow: hidden!important;
}


}
```

Comment: Hi, please fix your link to fiddle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your navbar isn't showing is because your `navbar-header` code is only within the `@media (min-width: 768px) {...` media query. And you have the navbar to hide on medium and large screens.

I've posted a fork [here with it showing up on the larger screens](https://jsfiddle.net/insanealec/ggp88ag7/2/).

You have `hidden-md hidden-lg` in the class for your `nav` in addition to what I said above about the `navbar-header` class only being contained within your media query.

In order to fix the scrollbar disappearing on the larger screens add `overflow-y: auto!important;` in your `.navbar-collapse.collapse.in`. This overrides the bootstrap implementation making it `visible` on the `(min-width: 768px)`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've still got the same issue. If the width is over 992, the background color when the nav bar is collapsed disappears on the last 3 links and I lose the scrollbar.

Comment: By using the inspector, it looks like there's an `.navbar-collapse.in{ overflow-y: auto}` that has a `min-width: 768px` on it, preventing the contents from being in a scroll-bar-box over that limit. I'm looking for the source of that in your code now.

Comment: That's probably a native bootstrap css line as its not something I've put in. I tried putting in .navbar-collapse .collapse.in {max-height: 500px;} seemed to cure my issue by making the collapsed box taller, but it only worked  in Safari. I still have issues with IE, Chrome and Firefox...

Comment: You beat me to it! I just added more to my answer and updated the fiddle to show the edit.